# Как превратить символы ASCII ( '+' '-' '*' '/' '%' ) в операторы Java

Tags: java, строки, char, ascii

Собственно вопрос можно ли как то распарсить эти символы в операторы?

Что бы я смог написать:

`System.out.println(8 (неизвестнаяМнеМагия('+')) 6);`

И получить на выход число 14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так можно:

```
int a = 8;
int b = 6;
String[] operators = {"+", "-", "*", "/", "%"};
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
for (String operator : operators){
    Object result = engine.eval(a + operator + b);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Вывод:

```
14
2
48
1.3333333333333333
2
```

[jdoodle.com/a/nF9](http://jdoodle.com/a/nF9)